# How to determine that user was signed in because button was clicked, not because auto sign in

Tags: javascript, google-signin

Simple button in HTML:

```
<div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>
```

and appropriate function:

```
function onSignIn(googleUser) {

  var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();

  localStorage.setItem("name", profile.getName());
  localStorage.setItem("email", profile.getEmail());
  localStorage.setItem("url", profile.getImageUrl());
  localStorage.setItem("id", profile.getId());

}
```

Is there a way to determine whether the user is signed in because the user clicked google sign in button or user was signed in automatically on load.

How can I prevent this?

Or in the other way, how can I log user out from the web app? Maybe the user will not be auto signed in.

After successful login, I redirect user to admin panel, and there is possibility to log out... but logout simply doesn't work.